# Is $L = \{ \langle \langle \ M\ \rangle \rangle \ | \ M \ \text{does not accept}\ 010 \} $ Turing recognizeable?

Tags: turing-machines, undecidability

I'm working on the following problem:

> Is the following language Turing recognizable (recursively enumerable)
>   ?
>
> $$L = \{ \langle \langle \ M\ \rangle \rangle \ | \ M \ \text{does not
> > accept}\ 010 \} $$

The way I see it: Suppose that a machine $M$ loops forever on $010$. If a $TM$ recognizes $L$, it should accept $M$ in that case. But that means that it should know if $M$ loops forever or not, which is not possible. So, $L$ is not Turing recognizable.

Is my proof correct, and can it be more formal?

Comment: It's not a proof, its mostly hand waving and (your) intuition. To show $L$ does not belong in a certain class, you must show a specific TM reduction to another TM language that is known not to be in that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are presenting an argument which falls short of being a proof. In particular, it is not clear why a Turing machine recognizing $L$ should know whether $M$ loops forever or not; indeed, it is not so clear what do you mean by *know* in this context.

Here is one way a proof could go. Suppose that $L$ were r.e. The language of Turing machines which do accept $010$ is also r.e. By running both machines in parallel, we can *decide* whether a given Turing machine accepts $010$, i.e., we could solve the halting problem, which we know is undecidable. Therefore $L$ cannot be r.e.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer! Now, I understand the proof you are presenting, but I don't quite get why my argument is not a proof. Could you be more elaborate on that?

Comment: Your claim "But that means that it should know if $M$ loops forever or not" is unsubstantiated.

Comment: So is this specific claim false, or have I not provided a solid proof of it?

Comment: You should explain why "that means that it should know if $M$ loops forever or not", and indeed what "know" means in this context.